# Reddit Pushshift PSAW error : AttributeError: 'Submission' object has no attribute 'd_'

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, reddit, praw

I am using Pushshift, sometimes the code below works and sometimes it does not.

```
start_epoch=int(dt.datetime(2021, 1, 30).timestamp())
end_epoch=int(dt.datetime(2021, 6, 20).timestamp())

api_request_generator = api.search_submissions(
                        after=start_epoch,
                        before=end_epoch,
                        subreddit='wallstreetbets',
                        score = ">100",
                        limit=1000,
                        filter=['title','score', 'id', 'url','author','created_utc'])

submissions = list()
for element in api_request_generator:
    submissions.append(element.d_)
```

I ran this last night and I was able to get it to work without the error:

> AttributeError: 'Submission' object has no attribute 'd_'

When I print each line of api_request_generator, I just get an id, I don't get all of the information that should come with it. Not sure what to do.

Also I noticed that when it was working and I had my limit to 2000 it was grabbing 200, and when I changed it to 3000 it would grab 300. Does the code just remove the last 0 for some reason?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Did you find the error or a way to make it work? I have the same error right now.